# How to insert a string between fields using nested category

Tags: php, categories

I need to show the records of my menu table grouped by category and separate them using a plus sign.
I don’t know much about PHP but I found this code on Internet and adapted it to show my records grouped by category. This is the code I have:

```
<?php
$catnew = '';  
do {  
$cat = $rmenu['op_name']; 
  if ($catnew != $cat) { 
    $catnew = $cat ?>

     <p> <strong><?php echo $rmenu['op_name']; ?></strong> </p>
    <?php } ?>     

     <?php 
     $varname = $rmenu['pla_name'] . "+";
     echo $varname; ?> 


<?php } ?>
```

With this code I get the following output:

**OPTION A**

Salad + Rice + Beans +

**OPTION B**

Chicken + Bread + Soup +

**I neet to show records like this:**

**OPTION A**

Salad + Rice + Beans

**OPTION B**

Chicken + Bread + Soup

My problem is to show the plus sign just between the fields not at the end or at the beginning. I have spent hours trying to figure this out but I haven’t found a solution. I will appreciate any help about this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check if $varname is empty. If not add on the plus before concatenating pla_name to it:

```
$catnew = '';  
do {  
    $cat = $rmenu['op_name']; 
    if ($catnew != $cat) { 
      $catnew = $cat;
      echo "<p> <strong>".$rmenu['op_name']."</strong> </p>";
    }
    //
    if ($varname != ""){
        $varname = $varname." + ";
    }
    $varname = $varname.$rmenu['pla_name'];
    echo $varname;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I had to declare $varname first. It took me sometime to figure out where to place it but I got it. You solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the final code:

```
do {  
    $cat = $rmenu['op_nombre'];

    if ($catnew != $cat) { 
      $catnew = $cat;
      echo "<p> <strong>".$rmenu['op_nombre']."</strong> </p>";
      $varname = '';
    }
    //

    if ($varname != ""){
        $varname = " + ";
    }
    $varname = $varname.$rmenu['pla_nombre'];
    echo $varname;
}
```